# Javascript convert Unicode Octal bytes to text

Tags: javascript, unicode, encoding, character-encoding, octal

I'm trying to convert a series of Octal bytes to text using Javascript as follows:

The input is \330\265 the output should be ص

The following tools managed to do that successfully:

- http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/octal/
- http://encodertool.com/octal

I'm trying to replicate this logic

Answer (score 5):

This is a very simple task, all you need to do is use the `Number.toString(radix)` method to convert a decimal integer value that you get back from `String.charCodeAt(index)` to encode the string.

Using a combination of `String.fromCharCode(charCode)` and `parseInt(numberString, radix)`, you can decode the octal value by using the value 8 for the radix and passing it to the `fromCharCode` method.

### Program Results

```
Input:   Hello World
Encode:  110 145 154 154 157 040 127 157 162 154 144
Decode:  Hello World
```

### Updated code

```js
const
  bytesToChars  = (bytes)    => bytes.map(byte => String.fromCharCode(parseInt(byte, 10))),
  charsToBytes  = (chars)    => chars.map(char => char.charCodeAt(0)),
  decToOctBytes = (decBytes) => decBytes.map(dec => dec.toString(8).padStart(3, '0')),
  octToDecBytes = (octBytes) => octBytes.map(oct => parseInt(oct, 8)),
  encode        = (str)      => decToOctBytes(charsToBytes(str.split(''))).join(' '),
  decode        = (octBytes) => bytesToChars(octToDecBytes(octBytes.split(/\s/))).join('');
  
let octBytes, str;
console.log('Input: ', str = 'Hello World');
console.log('Encode:', octBytes = encode(str));
console.log('Decode:', decode(octBytes));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

### Original code

```js
/* Redirect console output to HTML. */ document.body.innerHTML = '';
console.log=function(){document.body.innerHTML+=[].slice.apply(arguments).join(' ')+'\n';};

var octBytes, str;
console.log('Input: ', str = "Hello World");
console.log('Encode:', octBytes = encode(str));
console.log('Decode:', decode(octBytes));

function encode(str) {
  return decToOctBytes(charsToBytes(str.split(''))).join(' ');
}

function decode(octBytes) {
  return bytesToChars(octToDecBytes(octBytes.split(' '))).join('');
}

function charsToBytes(chars) {
  return chars.map(function(char) {
    return char.charCodeAt(0);
  });
}

function bytesToChars(bytes) {
  return bytes.map(function(byte) {
    return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(byte, 10));
  });
}

function decToOctBytes(decBytes) {
  return decBytes.map(function(dec) {
    return ('000' + dec.toString(8)).substr(-3);
  });
}

function octToDecBytes(octBytes) {
  return octBytes.map(function(oct) {
    return parseInt(oct, 8);
  });
}
```

```css
body { font-family: monospace; white-space: pre; }
```

Comment: This solution is not working with non-ascii characters, trying the character in my example ص I get 065 and once converted back I'm getting the character 5. What I'm expecting to get is 330, 265. I guess the issue here is converting two bytes into one character.